# 'DevExpress.Blazor.DxDataGridColumn' does not have a property matching the name 'DisplayFormatString'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, devexpress, blazor, dx-data-grid

Here is the code

```
<DxDataGrid Data="@dischargeBoards"
                ShowFilterRow="true"
                ShowPager="true"
                ShowGroupPanel="true">
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(DischargeGetBoardVisits.DischargeDateExp)" Caption="D/C Exp"  DisplayFormatString="D" EditFormatString="d"></DxDataGridColumn>

    </DxDataGrid>
```

How to fix this issue and how can i change the font size for this grid.

Comment: Can you upload your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [DxDataGridColumn](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxDataGridColumn._members) doesn't have the DisplayFormatString and EditFormatString properties, you can show data in the required format by formatting it manually. So, the algorithm is the following:

1. Get data.
2. Format it.
3. Assign your formatted data to "dischargeBoards".

P.S. Currently, DxDataGridDateEditColumn and DxDataGridSpinEditColumn have the DisplayFormatString property: [DisplayFormatString](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.Base.DxDataGridDateEditColumnBase.DisplayFormatString), [DisplayFormatString](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.Base.DxDataGridSpinEditColumnBase.DisplayFormatString)

As for changing the font size of the grid, set its [CssClass](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.Base.DxComponentBase.CssClass) property (for example, to the "my-grid" value) and apply the following CSS rule:

```css
    .my-grid, .my-grid .btn   {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```